# How to define custom user id for relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I have a Laravel 9 forum project and for the `Question` Model, I added this:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

And for `User` Model, I added this:

```
public function questions()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Question::class);
}
```

Basically, every question has a field named `creator_id` and I want to connect the relationship between these two Models based on this field.

So how can I do that?

Answer (score 6):

[This part](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) of the documentation shows you how to set those relationships. It suggest doing the following:

**Question model**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'creator_id');
}
```

**User model**

```
public function questions()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Question::class, 'creator_id');
}
```